# How can I tell what version of OpenGL my machine supports on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, opengl, gpu

How can I tell what OpenGL versions are supported on my (Arch Linux) machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ sudo pacman -S mesa-demos
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

Answer (score 10):

`glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`

Comment: That's not a program installed by default, but it is available in the AUR. I'm guessing there is no default program to do this?

Comment: @JeroenBollen It's in the `mesa-demos` package in extra. You can also use `glewinfo` if you have glew already installed.

Answer (score -1):

```
glxinfo | awk '/OpenGL version/ {print $4}'
```

Install "mesa-demos" if it does not work. :)

Comment: This command didn't output anything for me.

Comment: mesa-demos is installed? http://funkyimg.com/view/2g21m

Comment: Using a fixed column number is not going to be viable, specially over different versions. One might change the output format in different releases.